# Reading comic books with Scala

Tags: scala

Right now I'm opening comic book files (.cbr & cbz) with the following code, but I feel it could be done better. How would you go about it?

```
@throws(classOf[Exception])
def extract(filePath: String): File = {
    val unZip = new runCommand(Seq("7z", "x", "-y", filePath, s"-o${tempLocation}"))
    if (unZip.exitValue == 0){
        new File(tempLocation)
    }else{
        throw new Exception(unZip.errValue)
    }
}
@throws(classOf[Exception])
def preExtract(filePath: String): File = {
    try {
        filePath.split("\\.").last match {
            case "cbz" => extract(filePath)
            case "cbr" => extract(filePath)
            case _ =>
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Incorrect file extension for file: " + filePath)
        }
    } catch {
        case ex: Exception =>
            throw ex
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look up on using `scala.util.Try` instead of catching and rethrowing exceptions. [Here](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html) is a great article on the topic.

Now, I'm not familiar with the `runCommand()` function you use, maybe it's one of your own? In that case you might be able to modify it to return the error code wrapped in an `Option`, or `None` if no errors occurred. If so, your snippet can be implemented as a single function with two nested `match` blocks:

```
def extract(filePath: String): Try[File] = filePath match {
  case str if str.endsWith(".cbz") || str.endsWith(".cbr") =>
    runCommand(Seq(...)) match {
      case None => new File(tempLocation)
      case Some(errValue) => throw new UnzipFailedException(errValue)
    }
  case _ => throw new InvalidArgumentException(s"Incorrect file extension for file: $filePath")
}
```

I didn't test this code, but maybe it's of some help.

Comment: I'm away from my computer now, and can't test if this works. I'm curious why you are using pattern matching instead of an if statement?

Comment: Semantically there is no difference, I guess it's mostly a matter of preference. In simple cases the difference is neglible, but in general I find that a `match` will result in clearer and more concise code, especially when dealing with polymorphic checks or using deconstructors. You could rewrite the above code with `if`expressions and see which version you prefer.